# Apache Config Mime Types: xlsx files are being interpreted as zip files on download, why?

Tags: apache, excel, zip, mime-types

**Background:** For some reason, whenever a user tries to open an xslx (excel 2007) file from our intranet using MSIE, the file download dialog interprets it as a "zip" file.

Admittedly, xslx files really *are* zip files, but we don't want that behavior. Just open in Excel, please.

**Question:**

Firefox, OTOH, opens the files normally. Is it possible that the fault is my apache configs? or is this a client-browser-only issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason is IE's strange MIME sniffing behaviour: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms775147.aspx. It basically tries to determine to the file type of a file by looking into its contents, somehow like Linux's `file` tool.

Comment: So, would you know, is there a way to disable this or reconfigure the browser to stop this behavior?

Answer (score 4):

You must add some new MIME-TYPES on the web-server-side.

See the [comment-thread on this windowsnerd.com page](http://windowsnerd.com/2009/04/17/xlsx-and-docx-are-being-saved-as-a-zip-file-in-explorer/) (from 2009):

> Add this to a .htaccess file and throw it on your site: AddType
>   application/vnd.openxmlformats .docx .pptx .xlsx .xltx . xltm .dotx
>   .potx .ppsx
>
> Should fix many of the problems.

Alternatively, you can add this to the mime.types file located in the config  directory of your Apache web server

```
application/vnd.ms-word.document.macroEnabled.12 .docm
application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document docx
application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.template dotx
application/vnd.ms-powerpoint.template.macroEnabled.12 potm
application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.presentationml.template potx
application/vnd.ms-powerpoint.addin.macroEnabled.12 ppam
application/vnd.ms-powerpoint.slideshow.macroEnabled.12 ppsm
application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.presentationml.slideshow ppsx
application/vnd.ms-powerpoint.presentation.macroEnabled.12 pptm
application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.presentationml.presentation pptx
application/vnd.ms-excel.addin.macroEnabled.12 xlam
application/vnd.ms-excel.sheet.binary.macroEnabled.12 xlsb
application/vnd.ms-excel.sheet.macroEnabled.12 xlsm
application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet xlsx
application/vnd.ms-excel.template.macroEnabled.12 xltm
```

http://www.webdeveloper.com/forum/showthread.php?t=162526