# Jsp : download excel file converts to .zip file in linux environment

Tags: java, jsp

I am downloading excel file from (.xlsx) my jsp webpage. its working fine in windows machine.
However, when I'm deploying the same application into linux environment, the downloading excel sheet converting it to .Zip file

Could you please advise?

Comment: Provide the code that generates the file to be downloaded in your application.

Comment: <td class="header1" width="100%" align="center">Please            download the excel sheet from the link <font color='Blue'><a             href="folderCreation/folder_creation.xlsx"             style="color: blue; font-size: 15px; text-decoration: none;"           > Folder Creation</a></font>.          </td>

Comment: Application/WebContent/folderCreation/folder_creation.xlsx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `xlsx` is nothing more the `zip` file with xml files inside. Add this to your `.htaccess` in Apache:

```
AddType application/vnd.ms-word.document.macroEnabled.12 docm
AddType application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document docx
AddType application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.template dotx
AddType application/vnd.ms-powerpoint.template.macroEnabled.12 potm
AddType application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.presentationml.template potx
AddType application/vnd.ms-powerpoint.addin.macroEnabled.12 ppam
AddType application/vnd.ms-powerpoint.slideshow.macroEnabled.12 ppsm
AddType application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.presentationml.slideshow ppsx
AddType application/vnd.ms-powerpoint.presentation.macroEnabled.12 pptm
AddType application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.presentationml.presentation pptx
AddType application/vnd.ms-excel.addin.macroEnabled.12 xlam
AddType application/vnd.ms-excel.sheet.binary.macroEnabled.12 xlsb
AddType application/vnd.ms-excel.sheet.macroEnabled.12 xlsm
AddType application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet xlsx
AddType application/vnd.ms-excel.template.macroEnabled.12 xltm
AddType application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.template xltx
```

To work with `IE`, copy the above mentioned `MIME` types in the `conf/httpd.conf` file of `Apache`.

Or add below content in your **web.xml**:

```
  <mime-mapping> 
      <extension>xlsx</extension> 
      <mime-type>application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet</mi‌​me-type> 
  </mime-mapping>
```

Moreover you can look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1647339/apache-config-mime-types-xlsx-files-are-being-interpreted-as-zip-files-on-downl) discussing the same problem.

Comment: I am using tomcat 7. its working fine in Chrome browser but not working in IE 9.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I have created httpd.conf and placed under tomcat/conf. i have stopped and started the tomcat server but still having same issue.

Comment: It should be in `Apache` not in `tomcat`. This link might help you : http://askubuntu.com/questions/258780/how-to-add-mime-type-for-the-apache-webserver

Comment: I am using only tomcat7 web container not apache.

Comment: Updated answer again with link which you can follow:)

Comment: issue has been fixed by adding below into application web.xml           <mime-mapping>
    <extension>xlsx</extension>
    <mime-type>application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet</mime-type>
 </mime-mapping>

Comment: Congrats, I updated the answer as per your comment, accept the answer for new reader:)